# My former self is still inside of me... you'd only care when I'm inside of you

Tags: riddle, word

*I am a four letter word and I was strong.*

*Sadly got reversed and now I am weak.*

*But... my former self is still inside of me.*

*You would only care if I'm inside of you.*

---

What was I, and what am I now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> NORI, used to be IRON?

I am a four letter word and I was strong.

Sadly got reversed and now I am weak.

> Iron is a strong metal, but nori tears easily.

But... my former self is still inside of me.

You would only care if I'm inside of you.

> Nori contains iron, a nutrition fact that someone eating nori might care about.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a stretch, but are you

> you were **MEAN** and now **ANAEMIC**

I am a four letter word and I was strong.

> **MEAN** is a four letter word and shows up as a synonym for strong

Sadly got reversed and now I am weak.

> **ANAEMIC** contains **MEAN** reversed and means weak

But... my former self is still inside of me.

> **MEAN** is in **ANAEMIC** albeit reversed

You would only care if I'm inside of you.

> you would care if you were **ANAEMIC**